# wrong answer - can it be removed?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The question linked below has only one answer, which is totally wrong. Unfortunately, Google has picked it up and will show it as the highlighted result when searching for "remove toolbar modern web part".

I flagged the answer, hoping that moderators would delete it, but it is still there. This answer should be removed, so Google does not list it as the best match. I hate it when I come across scenarios like this and this is one of the few times that I feel I can help do something about it.

Thoughts?

[image]

[Hide Toolbar for list webpart on modern page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250280/hide-toolbar-for-list-webpart-on-modern-page)

Comment: Consider giving feedback to the Google's result too by clicking the "Feedback" button on the bottom right.

Comment: Hello, removing the answer not means it will not be highlighted in Google search result, I agree with Andrew to report the link as not helpful to Google! plus downvote the answer as you did! 
As a moderator, I don't think it's a good idea to delete the provided answers directly in case of it's wrong! it's the responsibility of SE members to downvote it in case it's not a useful or wrong answer! (5 downvotes will delete it automatically)! 
The moderator should moderate the posts and answers that don't follow the SE rules as spam, I have the same issue, link only etc.

Comment: Thanks. I used the feedback link. Let's see what comes out of it. Meanwhile, if a few others could downvote the wrong answer, that would also help the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer deleted, and reputations restored. We don't want wrong answers highlighted at Google. Thanks for letting us know (y)